# Need to give time-stamp to log file in springboot framework

Tags: spring-boot

My `logback-spring.xml` is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />


<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

and application.properties is a below.

```
spring.application.name=fetcher Application
logging.file = spring.log
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: where is the problem? just do it: `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3493036/patrick) said, just replace ...

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
```

With ...

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS}.log}"/>
```

However, this would mean that your log file would always be named for the time at which it was created, is this definitely required? A fixed name for a log file might make it easier to find/script around. A more common approach might be to name the *current* file "spring.log" and specify a date suffix when rolling it. For example:

```
<appender name="FILEOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.dir}/spring.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${log.dir}/spring-%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        ...
    </rollingPolicy>
    ...
</appender>
```